# Can not perform R markdown on word,PDF and HTML

Tags: r

I'm getting this error message whenever I'm trying to knit my rmarkdown into PDF,Word and HTML.

ordinary text without R code

|...                                                                   |   4%
label: setup (with options)
List of 1
$ include: logi FALSE

|....                                                                  |   5%
ordinary text without R code

|.....                                                                 |   7%
label: unnamed-chunk-1

Quitting from lines 21-26 (yvj349_MBO_Midterm.RMD)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a network issue that your system just failed to establish a connection with CRAN server.

I think if you can show your rmd code, people here may do more help.